# Loading File in Datastage

Tags: file, path, etl, filepath, datastage

Can we use a file present on desktop and by giving the path of it in the sequential file stage of DataStage, can we use it? Or only Unix specified path is used? Give me some reasons for it.

Comment: Google search can def answer this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataStage sequential file stage takes any path of the server where the DataStage engine is installed. So if your engine is installed on Windows it will be Windows style paths - for engines on Unix it will be Unix style paths.

So if your file is not on the same server as te engine you have to transfer it first, use some FTP functionality or map a network drive (ie. SAMBA).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any file by giving full path of it whether it is on desktop or anywhere(same server). Same applies for Unix system

Answer (score 0):

Datastage is installed either on some host or on local machine. If you have datastage installed on your local machine/localhost, then the answer is YES. You can have a file placed on your desktop and use it. And if DS is installed on some remote server, then we can not use placing on our local desktop.